# Linear Interpolation in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I work with annual mileage for each customer. Years are consecutive in range 2009-2022, so i have no gaps in years and some customers for instance can have records from 2009 to 2020, and so on, but all years are consecutive there are no gaps. The issue with Annual_Mlg is that there are NULL values time to time. NULLs appear randomly: there can be 3 consecutive NULLs at the beginning of range for certain customer or in the middle there  can be 4 NULLs, and last 3 values can be NULLs as well. So NULL values are random. I need to have mileage for EVERY SINGLE YEAR. If mileage was 0 that is fine. I just should use it in computation. 0 mileage means customer was not traveling that year at all. So that number is acceptable just like any other valid mileage. By valid mileage i mean non-negative mileage, and table with which i work has ONLY non-negative mileage (so valid mileage). I need to get rid of NULLs and where i have NULLs i use either previous record or next record or interpolation should be used to get rid of NULLs completely. There should be NO default value. I DO HOPE THAT THERE IS A CODE BETTER TO FIX MY PROBLEM. ALSO IF THERE AN EASIER WAY TO FIX PROBLEM IN 'R' (programming language) then I am ALL EARS, however i have not attempted to solve it in 'R' since i suck more in 'R' then in MS SQL.

I have created Previous Mlg and Next Mlg in order to do interpolation if NULL value is sandwiched between non-NULL 2 values. That seems to be working. Annual_mlg this field where the original values are in. Final_mlg this is where i need to have all values as non-NULLs. I used COALESCE to get rid of NULLs to some extent. I am a relatively new in SQL and i have not enough coding skills to tackle this type of problem on my own it seems to be. So if to take a look at what i have inside COALESCE i can explain my logic.
3rd value inside COALESCE deals with case when there are 2 consecutive NULLs somewhere in the middle of 2009-2022 range and then code comes to first NULL it takes previous mileage that is Prev_Mlg, but then for 2nd NULL it takes previous Mileage which i just got and averages it with next non-NULL value.
I use bunch of lead() and lag() those are to account for cases when there are bunch of records with NULLs at either beginning or at the end. This code does not obviously solve all problems and looks like a joke.
I am looking to have more meaningful code. NOTE: there should not be a default value, all NULLs should be replaced and the logic for this goes as follows:

1. If there is a NULL sandwiched between 2 non-NULLs then code should interpolate;
2. if there is NULL at the beginning of range then it should be replaced with FIRST non-NULL value in range
   by range i mean years from 2009 - 2022
3. if there is NULL at the end of range then it should be replaced by FIRST non-NULL value (if to count from the end of the range)
4. Once NULL value is replaced then this should be used in interpolation. I will provide examples what kind of result i need to get.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I AM REALLY STRUGGLING!!!

```
SELECT 
Customer,
Year,
Final_Mlg = COALESCE(Annual_Mlg, (Prev_Mlg + Next_Mlg)/2, 
(lag(Final_Mlg) over (partition by Customer order by Year) + Next_Mlg)/2, Prev_Mlg, Next_Mlg,
lead(Final_Mlg) over (partition by Customer order by Year), 
lead(Final_Mlg,2) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,3) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,4) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,5) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,6) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,7) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,8) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,9) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,10) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lead(Final_Mlg,11) over (partition by Customer order by Year),

lag(Final_Mlg) over (partition by Customer order by Year), 
lag(Final_Mlg,2) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,3) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,4) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,5) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,6) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,7) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,8) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,9) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,10) over (partition by Customer order by Year),
lag(Final_Mlg,11) over (partition by Customer order by Year)),

Annual_Mlg,
Prev_Mlg,
Next_Mlg

FROM #table2
ORDER BY 
Customer,
Year
```

CASE 1: couple of values are consecutive NULLs at the BEGINNING of range. There is a desired result below.

| Year | Customer | Annual_Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | A | NULL(Should be Replaced by 3) |
| 2010 | A | NULL(Should be Replaced by 3) |
| 2011 | A | NULL(Should be Replaced by 3) |
| 2012 | A | 3 |
| 2013 | A | 4 |
| 2014 | A | 5 |
| 2015 | A | 6 |
| 2016 | A | 7 |
| 2017 | A | 8 |
| 2018 | A | 9 |
| 2019 | A | 10 |
| 2020 | A | 11 |
| 2021 | A | 12 |
| 2022 | A | 13 |

CASE 2: couple of values are consecutive NULLs at the END of range.

| Year | Customer | Annual_Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | A | 3 |
| 2010 | A | 3 |
| 2011 | A | 3 |
| 2012 | A | 3 |
| 2013 | A | 4 |
| 2014 | A | 5 |
| 2015 | A | 6 |
| 2016 | A | 7 |
| 2017 | A | 8 |
| 2018 | A | 9 |
| 2019 | A | 10 |
| 2020 | A | NULL(Should be Replaced by 10) |
| 2021 | A | NULL(Should be Replaced by 10) |
| 2022 | A | NULL(Should be Replaced by 10) |

CASE 3: There are some NULLs in between non-NULL values.

| Year | Customer | Annual_Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | A | 1 |
| 2010 | A | NULL (Should be replaced by 1.5) |
| 2011 | A | 2 |
| 2012 | A | 3 |
| 2013 | A | 4 |
| 2014 | A | NULL (Should be replaced by 4.5) |
| 2015 | A | 5 |
| 2016 | A | NULL (Should be replaced by 5.5) |
| 2017 | A | 6 |
| 2018 | A | NULL (Should be replaced by 6) |
| 2019 | A | NULL (Should be replaced by 6.5) |
| 2020 | A | 7 |
| 2021 | A | 8 |
| 2022 | A | 8 |

Comment: A small Data Sample and Desired results would be more useful than a wall of text ... TLDR

Comment: Please reformat the desired results, it's unreadable as is.